# Does Vim in console/tty have same colors set as in terminal/xterm-256color?

Tags: vimrc, terminal, console

When I setup vim for colors in terminal, I'd like it has the same as in console, so Does console support 256color? as I'm using xterm-256color in a terminal right now?

Comment: What console on what system? That sounds like a question that is better asked in your operating system forum

Comment: tty console and on archlinux.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/254249/303213

Comment: So we can't live in peace without having a messing x-windows installed. Maybe one day tty will support 256color :D, hope I still alive til that day.